# Webpack Error In Project That Uses Svelte with Wrapped React Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, build, svelte

I'm currently working on a Svelte-based project that has large component written in Rust and then wrapped using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess-react) package. Most of my issues have come from Webpack, however.

I have read through a couple of posts on similar issues to this, but enabling emit for these files does not seem to work, when I enable emit, I get those issues in addition to new type errors.

After spending a couple of days trying to fix my Webpack configuration, I've gotten completely stuck on this

```
ERROR in ./src/client/ClientFiles/m-editor/leanclient.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for ./src/client/ClientFiles/m-editor/leanclient.ts.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (./node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:55:18)
    at successLoader (./node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:42:5)
    at Object.loader (./node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:23:5)
```

I'm guessing that there's probably some more fundamental issue with my project which is why I've included my Webpack configuration along with my project structure.

Here is my Webpack configuration

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const prod = mode === 'development';
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


  const babelOptions = {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'], 
  };


module.exports = {
    
    entry: {//The first module we start building a dependency graph around
        'build/bundle': ['./src/main.js']
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: { //changes paths when we query for modules
            svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte/src/runtime') //TODO: This is probably causing all of my issues
        },
        extensions: [".tsx", '.js', '.svelte', ".ts", '.mjs', ".jsx" ], //what file extensions we can viably resolve
        fallback: { //I think it goes to that stupid directory page because of browserify
         "http": require.resolve("stream-http"), //I had to install these as packages from npm like "npm i path-browserify"
         "path": require.resolve("path-browserify")
        },
        mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
        conditionNames: ['svelte', 'browser', 'import']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[id].js'
    },
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.svelte$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'svelte-loader',
                options: {
                    compilerOptions: {
                        dev: !prod
                    },
                    emitCss: true,
                    hotReload: !prod
                }
            }
        },
            {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: [/server/, /node_modules/],
              use: [{
                loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
                  options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                     compilerOptions: {
                        
                     }
                  },
              }]
            },
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "noEmit": false,

                    },
                },
              }],
              exclude:[/server/,
                  /node_modules\/(?!vscode)/,
                  /node_modules\/(?!monaco_editor)/,
                  /node_modules\/(?!lean4)/,
                  /ClientFiles\/m-editor\/(?!abbreviation)/
              ], // Allow .ts imports from node_modules/lean4
            },
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
                include: [
                  /server/,
                  /node_modules\/vscode/,
                  /node_modules\/monaco_editor/,
                  /node_modules\/lean4/,
                  /ClientFiles\/m-editor\/(abbreviation)/,
                  /ClientFiles\/m-editor\/(taskgutter.ts)/
                ],
              use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "noEmit": true,

                    },
                },
              }]
            },
        { 
            test: /leanclient\.ts$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "noEmit": true,
                    "transpileOnly": true}
                }
            }]
        },
            {
              test: /\.svg$/,
              issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
              use: [{
                loader: "@svgr/webpack",
                options: { dimensions: false }
              },
              ],
            },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]

        }
        ]
    },
    mode,
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css'
        }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        //prod && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),

    ],
    devtool: prod ? false : 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.